# Need to join 3 tables in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am a newbie at `MySQL`..... I am trying to `left join` 3 tables one contains **some_id,name,count,descr** and second one has **id,some_id,uni_id** and the last one has **uni_id,price,added,etc** So when i try to join these three tables it says that there's no such field named `descr`

What could be the best way to join these tables without modifying structure of them?

Comment: what are the names of the tables?

Comment: please provide table names and some data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the following schema:

- `table1(some_id, name, count, descr)`, where `some_id` is the primary key;
- `table2(id, some_id, uni_id)`, where `some_id` is a foreign key to `table1`;
- `table3(uni_id, price, added)`, where `uni_id` is a foreign key to `table2`.

All you need to do is a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` between the three tables:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 t1 LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON (t1.some_id = t2.some_id)
  LEFT JOIN table3 ON (t2.uni_id = t3.uni_id)
```

#### References:

- [Left Outer Join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Left_outer_join)
- [Join Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)

Answer (score 0):

It would be ideal if you could post the schema for your tables. Without seeing the query, it sounds like you've made a reference to a field that you may have aliased to the wrong table.

At the most basic level, "descr" doesn't exist as you've tried to reference it, but beyond that, its hard to say without seeing the query itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT descr
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table2.some_id = table1.some_id
LEFT JOIN table3 ON table3.uni_id = table2.uni_id
```

Should do the trick.